# Is there a maximum reasonable file size to attach to a MIME email with PHP?

Tags: php, email, iis-6, mime, attachment

I run PHP on IIS6.  I have some PHP that successfully sends a 1KB image as an attachment on an email.  When I try and attach a 500KB PDF however (having changed the Content-Type), it hangs and after a few minutes I get "FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout" (Error Number 258 (0x80070102)).

Any thoughts on why it's taking so long to attach the PDF?  The solution is not to increase the timeout limit, I can't have users sitting there for 3+ minutes while the file gets sent.

I've included my code below:

```
    $headers   = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from."\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n"; 
    $headers .="This is a multipart message in MIME format. \r\n\r\n";

    $headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset-iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= $text . "\r\n\r\n";

    $headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset-iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= $html  . "\r\n\r\n";

    $headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: image/png; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($path.$filename))); 
    $headers .= $attachment . "\r\n\r\n";

    $headers .= "--".$uid."\r\n\r\n";

    //send the email 
    $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $text, $headers );
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: And you are sure that it's not the actual generation of the PDF that makes the script time out?

Comment: this doesnt sound like the attachment filesize has anything to do with it. attachments size depends on the mail server settings and are usually at least 2mb

Comment: Hi, I'm not generating the PDF, I'm attaching PDFs from the file system.  I've tried attaching a 60KB PDF and 1KB PNG and it took 24 seconds.  If I add the 570KB PDF, it times out.

Comment: It's the encoding that's taking the time - if I remove the call the base64_encode, the email sends instantly, but the attachment is corrupt of course.

Answer (score 2):

Put the attachment in the message parameter of the mail() function instead of the additional headers parameter.

I ran into the same problem today and found that I couldn't submit large files as part of the headers parameter in the mail() function.

e.g.

```
$headers   = "From: ".$from."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from."\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n"; 
$body .="This is a multipart message in MIME format. \r\n\r\n";

$body .= "--".$uid."\r\n\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset-iso-8859-1\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n";
$body .= $text . "\r\n\r\n";

$body .= "--".$uid."\r\n\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset-iso-8859-1\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$body .= $html  . "\r\n\r\n";

$body .= "--".$uid."\r\n\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: image/png; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($path.$filename))); 
$body .= $attachment . "\r\n\r\n";

$body .= "--".$uid."\r\n\r\n";

//send the email 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```